# Filter dataset with %in% with pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I’m using filter to my dataset to select certain values from column:

```
%>%
filter(col1 %in% c(“value1”, “value2"))
```

How ever I don’t understand how to filter values in column with pattern without fully writing it. For example I also want all values which start with “value3” (“value33”, “value34”,....) along with “value1” and “value2”. Can I add grepl to that vector?

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions to do that:

```
df %>%
   filter(str_detect('^value[1-3]'))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use another tidyverse package to help, you can use `str_starts` from `stringr` to find strings that start with a certain value

```
dd %>% filter(stringr::str_starts(col1, "value"))
```

Comment: but if i have several patterns

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by that. It would be nice to include a simple [reproducible example]
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Include both rows that you want to match and those you don't so we can make sure the solution works.

Comment: I mean that in this way: “col1 %in% c(“value1”, “value2", “int_value”, “string_value”)” I can select several types of patterns, and with your method only one

Answer (score 0):

Here are few options in base R :

Using `grepl` :

```
subset(df, grepl('^value', b))

#  a        b
#1 1   value3
#3 3 value123
#4 4  value12
```

Similar option with `grep` which returns index of match.

```
df[grep('^value', df$b),]
```

However, a faster option would be to use `startsWith`

```
subset(df, startsWith(b, "value"))
```

All of this would select rows where column `b` starts with `"value"`.

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = c('value3', 'abcd', 'value123', 'value12', 'def'), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```